# How to run a command in Ruby that supports interaction but also allows access to its output?

Tags: ruby

Currently I am running commands like this:

```
system("bundle exec rspec spec")
```

This is great since it also supports interaction meaning it allows me to interact via `byebug` or `binding.pry` for example. However, I would also like to get the output of the `system` call which is not possible. Also, the exit code is useless to me--I only need the output of the command.

How can I achieve the same thing as `system` but also get access to its output? I have tried backticks but it doesn't support interaction.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `Kernel#system` or [`Kernel#spawn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) you can specify input and output streams as part of the method itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Open3.capture`:

```
require 'open3'
stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3('bundle exec rspec spec')
```

which is based on `Open3.popen3`:

```
require 'open3'
require 'byebug'
Open3.popen3('ls -la .') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  byebug
end
```

Comment: Not sure If I'm doing something wrong but this command just hangs if I have a `byebug` or `binding.pry` to halt execution. `system` will allow me to inspect the code. How can I achieve the same effect?

Comment: Ok, not sure why the command would hang. But I've screwed up the parameter naming in the `popen3` example and fixed that now.